# Azure Function Output Binding Event Grid Managed Identity

Tags: azure, azure-managed-identity, azure-eventgrid

Im trying to write an Azure function which has an Event Grid output binding, how do I configure it to use a manage identity instead of the topic key ?

```
    [Function("TestEventGrid")]
    [EventGridOutput(TopicEndpointUri = "MyEventGridTopicUriSetting", TopicKeySetting = "MyEventGridTopicKeySetting")]
    public async Task<MyEvent> Run([HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "post")] HttpRequestData req)
    {
        return await Task.FromResult(new MyEvent
        {
            Id = "123",
            Subject = "sub",
            EventType = "myevent",
            EventTime = DateTime.Now,
            Data = new TestData(),
            DataVersion = "1.0"
        });
    }
```

Comment: I'm trying to find the same info, please update this with an answer if you find out how to do this. The documentation is pretty severely lacking here. Since function apps can use managed identities, it certainly seems like it should be possible..

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `EventGridAttribute`, use `EventGridAsyncCollector`, which lives [nextdoor](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/tree/Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.EventGrid_3.2.1/sdk/eventgrid/Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.EventGrid/src/OutputBinding):

[image]

`EventGridAsyncCollector` uses `EventGridPublisherClient` behind [the scenes](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/blob/21af9e0913988961329a1d8a2b3d5cfc45e47b2b/sdk/eventgrid/Azure.Messaging.EventGrid/api/Azure.Messaging.EventGrid.netstandard2.0.cs#L231):

```cs
public EventGridPublisherClient(System.Uri endpoint, Azure.AzureKeyCredential credential) { }
```

`Azure.AzureKeyCredential credential` is what you are looking for.

UPDATE:
You should completely ditch `EventGridAttribute` and go for the lower level `EventGridPublisherClient`. Here's a link to how to use it: https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/tree/main/sdk/eventgrid/Azure.Messaging.EventGrid#authenticate-using-azure-active-directory

Answer (score 1):

I've implemented this feature in the SDK because our team needed it too, it's now available in version 3.3.0. You can use managed identity the same way as many other Azure-native bindings, by specifying the 'Connection' property instead of the TopicEndpointUri and TopicKey. As per the updated documentation:

> It is also possible to use Azure Identity with the output binding. To do so, set the Connection property to the name of your app setting that contains your Event Grid Topic endpoint along with a set of optional Identity information that is described in detail here. When setting the Connection property, the TopicEndpointUri and TopicKeySetting properties should NOT be set.

```cs
public static class CloudEventOutputBindingWithIdentityFunction
{
    [FunctionName("CloudEventOutputBindingWithIdentityFunction")]
    public static async Task<IActionResult> RunAsync(
        [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "get", "post", Route = null)] HttpRequest req,
        [EventGrid(Connection = "MyConnection")] IAsyncCollector<CloudEvent> eventCollector)
    {
        CloudEvent e = new CloudEvent("IncomingRequest", "IncomingRequest", await req.ReadAsStringAsync());
        await eventCollector.AddAsync(e);
        return new OkResult();
    }
}
```

> For local development, use the local.settings.json file to store the connection information:

```json
{
  "Values": {
    "myConnection__topicEndpointUri": "{topicEndpointUri}"
  }
}
```

References:

- [Azure WebJobs EventGrid client library for .NET - version 3.3.0](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/overview/azure/microsoft.azure.webjobs.extensions.eventgrid-readme?view=azure-dotnet#functions-that-uses-event-grid-output-binding)
- [Azure Event Grid output binding for Azure Functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-event-grid-output?tabs=python-v2%2Cisolated-process%2Cnodejs-v4%2Cextensionv3&pivots=programming-language-csharp#identity-based-authentication)

Comment: How do I make sure my managed identity is being used when I run  my Azure function locally? I have set the `connection` property, but I still receive "Unauthorized" when attempting to send data to my Event Grid topic.

Comment: Also, you mention some docs in your answer. Do you have a link?

Comment: @ddastrodd I've added supporting references to the answer. Managed identity in Visual Studio uses the account you are signed in to VS with. That account has to have the appropriate permissions to publish events, and your sign-in needs to be up-to-date (I just had issues with my refresh token being expired and needed to sign in again)

Comment: Thanks Andrew. For anybody else who hits this, I also needed to give myself Event Grid Contributor and Event Grid Data Sender permissions to make all this work (even though I already had Owner permissions). Not sure if I needed just one or the other, but added both to save time debugging.